# input type file validation message not going away in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-validate, file-io

I have a file upload field in my form and I am validating that field using jquery validation like the following:

My Input tag:

```
<input type="file" id=resume></input>
```

Validation:

```
$('myform').validate({

    rules:{
        resume : { required: true,  
                     accept: "pdf,txt"}  
    }  
    messages:{
        resume: {required: "this field is mandatory",  
                  accepts: "accepts pdf or txt"}  
    }  
});
```

Comment: Can you paste your snippet in jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 3):

You have several problems:

1) Invalid HTML.  `input` elements do not use closing tags.  They are "self-closing" with a `/>`.  Quotation marks around `resume` would also be a very good idea.

```
<input type="file" id="resume" />
```

2)  The jQuery Validate plugin **requires** that your form inputs each have a `name` attribute.  And when you declare rules inside `.validate()`, it's only the `name` which can be used as the target (see code below).

```
<input type="file" id="resume" name="resume" />
```

3) Your jQuery selector is invalid, and presumably missing the `#` character.  If the `<form>` contains `id="myform"`, then you must use this selector:

```
$('#myform')
```

4)  You are missing a comma between the `rules` and `messages` options.

5)  Inside your `messages` option, you misspelled the `accept` rule, and [the `accept` rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#mimetype) is only for **mime type**.   If you want to test the file extension, use [the `extension` rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension) and remember that you need to include the `additional-methods.js` file if you want to use this rule.

```js
$('#myform').validate({
    rules:{
        resume: {  // <- this refers to the NAME attribute, NOT id.
            required: true,  
            extension: "pdf,txt"
        }  
    },             // <-- comma is required here
    messages:{
        resume: {  // <- this refers to the NAME attribute, NOT id.
            required: "this field is mandatory",  
            extension: "accepts pdf or txt"
        }  
    }  
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/rgKXm/**